# Visibility of layers in OL 3.6.0

Tags: openlayers, visibility

I have several vector layers on map and when i try to toggle visibility of specific layer nothing happens, except for the layer which was added last. If i set visibility of that layer to false, all layers disappear, if i set it back to true all layers are visible again. Can someone explain me this behaviour?

Comment: Problem is solved, i had the same global variable for every vectorLayer source, which was everytime overwritten. So only the last layer had features.